# Can't get Uri from data.getData()

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to capture image and upload it to `Firebase`.
The problem is that i'm getting null from `data.getData()` in the `onActivityResult`.

I looked to web and couldn't find anything that worked for me in this case.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(intent,  CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

this is the `onActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Uri uri = data.getData();
StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child("labelPhoto").child(uri.getLastPathSegment())
filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
....rest of the code... }
```

I can't send to uri since i get null on `data.geData()`;

I tried a number of solutions, like saving the image as bmp and get this uri:

```
Bitmap bitmap= (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            captureImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/" + picName + ".jpg";
            File imageFile = new File(mPath);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;


            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                String temp = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/";
                uri=  Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                Log.d("TAG", uri.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                java.net.URI javaUri = java.net.URI.create(uri.toString());
                android.net.Uri androidUri = android.net.Uri.parse(uri.toString());
                StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child("labelPhoto").child(androidUri.toString());
filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
....rest of the code...}
```

add checks like:

```
  if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
```

and

```
if(data!=null)
```

the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Without any success.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: which phone and which os yoiu are using?

Comment: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`.

Comment: i use Huawei MediaPad 10.1 Link

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the standard Android camera app, you should pass the URI where you want the photo to be stored as an intent extra like this:

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(YOUR_FILE);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
intent(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```